# using ShareActionProvider somewhere else, not it ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

Sorry for the noob question, but I've always used ShareActionProvider from ActionBarSherlock. Now I don't want to use ActionBarSherlock at all - i want to use side menu and have a button for sharing - can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in a click listener or something similar.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Which should show a dialog like this:

[image: ACTION_SEND]